# Why are neodymium magnets ground into powder rather than cast?

Tags: material-science

According to Wikipedia, neodymium magnets are first cast into ingots, then milled into powder and sintered into final shapes.

Why not just cast them? Why bother milling? It seems like an extra step for no reason.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neodymium_magnet

Comment: Because sintering into shapes is easier than machining them, and reduces waste.

Comment: I can see this might be a factor but in that case I don't know why they'd control particle size so heavily (it literally goes through a cyclone separator to select a specific grain size). Are you sure it's not some magnet strength thing? https://idealmagnetsolutions.com/knowledge-base/how-neodymium-magnets-made/

Comment: The waste would just go straight back in, I don't understand why you think this answers the question. I don't think sintering is easier than machining. What does 'easier' mean in this context? I just don't understand why you'd write this.

Comment: Machining waste has cutting fluid. Or if you core out a sheet to make circular magnets you have to reprocess the sheet with lots of holes in it. Sintering is straightforward, and quite useful for brittle materials.

Comment: It could be for the same reason powdered steels exist: They're trying to achieve some set of characteristics in the crystal structure or grain which would otherwise be contradictory coming straight out of other processing methods (ie. liquid straight to solid).

Comment: By the way, there is a neodymium magnet process where the metal is technically cast. It's called "melt-spinning". Looking into why it's done that way rather than conventional casting might give clues.

Comment: Hello! This question might be more suitable for [engineering.se]. Please see [Are engineering questions appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4535/) for more information. Thanks!

Comment: OK. I think the physics here is that the energy required to orient a domain to the magnetic field is proportional to its dipole moment, which is proportional to its volume. So having lots of magnetic domains as small as possible means that the magnet ends up stronger for a given external driving field. I think @DKNguyen is completely right that it's analogous to powdered steel.

Comment: @Jonas please be less overzealous in enforcing the rules. Many of the most interesting physics questions don't look like physics questions. You can see this very clearly even in this forum. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes

This question in particular is still mid-resolution, it looks like there is a very interesting answer, and people are having to continue the conversation in the comments to figure it out because you have closed the topic too early.

Answer (score 2):

First watch [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM) by MinutePhysics and Veritasium.

It is a good explanation, but one point we care about was simplified away. Magnetic domains are tied to crystal structure. Crystal structure creates easy directions.

For example, an iron crystal has either a body centered cubic or face centered cubic structure. Each atom has nearest neighbors in various different directions. Nearest neighbor atoms tend to align N pole to S pole, like bar magnets. This can happen in any of the nearest neighbor directions. These are called "easy" directions because it is easy to magnetize an iron crystal in these directions.

[image]

Image from https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/delta-iron

Typically iron is made out of many microscopic crystals oriented in random directions. You can magnetize iron, making the magnetic field of each domain point in the same direction. But what you really get is the magnetic field of each domain pointing in the easy direction closest to the desired direction. Having domains point more or less in the right direction make iron a weaker magnet.

This is OK for iron. It gets magnetized enough for ordinary purposes. But sometimes you need the strongest magnet you can get. This would be a Neodymium magnet. When these are made, no expense is spared to being out their full strength.
See [How Neodymium Magnets are Made](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=how-neodymium-magnets-are-made)

The key point is they are reduced to a fine powder, so fine that each grain is a single domain. The grains are lined up so their easy directions are parallel. Then they are sintered - heated to tack them together into a single solid. As [All About Magnetization Direction](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=magnetization-direction) explains, orienting the easy directions makes the magnet 4 or 5 x stronger. (See [Temperature and Neodymium Magnets](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=temperature-and-neodymium-magnets) for an explanation of magnetic strength.)

Sintering has drawbacks. The material isn't nearly as strong as solid metal. It is fragile, breakable, and hard to machine. People use Neodymium magnets when they care more about magnetic strength than anything else.

Comment: Right, but why does having a really specific grain size make the magnet stronger than having lots of different grain sizes?

Comment: @MattTobias It might not be a specific grain size so much as the smallest possible grain size. And if there's a smallest grain size you can produce, you're just going to make the entire magnet that grain size because mixing the good stuff with the not so good stuff is just going to waste the good stuff. Just like powdered steel in knives. You want the carbides which make the knife hard to be small so it can be sharpened to a very fine edge, but if there's a bunch of large carbides mixed in there then it is kind of defeats the purpose of having the fine carbides.

Comment: @DKNguyen This makes a lot of sense, thank you.